# How to write a variadic-template function with objects as parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Consider the following functions (it uses the [CSV parser library from ben-strasser (github)](https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser))

```
void col1(const std::string &fn, Base *v0)
{
    io::CSVReader<2> in(fn);
    in.read_header(io::ignore_extra_column, "epoch", v0->column);
    double ign;
    while (in.read_row(ign, v0->value)) {
        v0->process();
    }
}

void col2(const std::string &fn, Base *v0, Base *v1)
{
    io::CSVReader<3> in(fn);
    in.read_header(io::ignore_extra_column, "epoch", v0->column, v1->column);
    double ign;
    while (in.read_row(ign, v0->value, v1->value)) {
        v0->process();
        v1->process();
    }
}
```

This function processes the value in column 2 of a CSV-file. `v0` of type `Base *` contains the member `value` which is filled by `read_row` and is processed in the `process`-method. `Base` is an interface-class of calculation methods (for exemple: one is Max, another one is MinMaxAvg).

How could I rewrite this function to accept any number of `Base *` arguments in order to process multiple columns?

`read_header` and `read_row` are variadic-template function and thus can accept any number of arguments, but they only work with scalars.

How do I expand/unpack the variadic-argument so that it calls or uses a member?

I tried some things, reading some examples, but I'm unable to create something which works, here is my current/ridicules code:

```
template<unsigned int COL>
void func(const std::string &fn, Base &... values)
{
     io::CSVReader<COL> in(fn);
     // that's it :-(
}
```

Comment: @OP: Should every `Base` from the variadic pack be processed just like `v0` in your first snippet, but with its own column in order?

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I'm adding my current version of Col2.

Comment: You are switching from pointers (Base*) to references (Base&) - intended?

Comment: No, not intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some well-placed pack expansions will work dandy:

```
template <class... Bases>
void col(const std::string &fn, Bases *... bases)
{
    io::CSVReader<sizeof...(Bases) + 1u> in(fn);
    in.read_header(io::ignore_extra_column, "epoch", bases->column...);
    double ign;
    while (in.read_row(ign, bases->value...)) {
        // Awful C++11 arbitrary expansion trick
        int dum[]{ 0, (void(
            bases->process()
        ), 0)... };
        (void) dum;

        // Alternative, sweet and beautiful C++17 fold expression
        // (void)(bases->process(), ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aconcagua it shouldn't be useful in this case to be fair. It's there to correctly handle the empty pack case, avoiding a zero-length array which would be ill-formed.

Comment: Could you explain what happens with `dum[]` and the 0 and the ,-operator?

Comment: @PatrickB. the goal is to have *somewhere* to perform our pack expansion. An array's initializer is nice becauseit guarantees left-to-right evaluation. The first zero is, as explained above, to handle the empty case. Then we need to stuff our arbitrary expression inside another expression that evaluates to an `int`. This is done by discarding our expression's result with `void()`, then swapping it out for a `0` via the comma operator.

Comment: What prevents us from writing `bases->process(), ...;` in C++11?

Comment: @PatrickB. C++11 has a pretty strict list of possible [expansion loci](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Expansion_loci) where expansion can take place. Unfortunately, a stand-alone expression isn't part of that list.

Comment: Great, thanks for all the explanations, I'm finally starting to understand variadic arguments. I'm getting afraid.

Comment: @PatrickB. My pleasure! The good news is, the expansion boilerplate is always the same, so you can [wrap it inside a macro](https://gitlab.com/D-z/glk/raw/master/include/glk/tmp/expand.h) and never bother with it again :)

Answer (score 1):

Use pack expansion operator `...` to unpack your variadic arguments.

```
template<typename... T> void nop(T&&...) { }

template<typename... Bases>
void func(const std::string &fn, Bases&&... bases)
{
   io::CSVReader<sizeof...(Bases) + 1> in(fn);

   in.read_header(io::ignore_extra_column, "epoch", bases->column...);
   double ign;
   while (in.read_row(ign, bases->value...)) {
    // multiple ways to call process on all values
    // prettier with C++17 stuff it seems
    nop((bases->process(), 0)...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two steps: first, we need to extend our function as desired:

```cpp
template <typename ... Bases>
void f(std::string const& s, Bases* ... values)
{
    io::CSVReader<sizeof...(Bases) + 1> in(s);
    in.read_header(io::ignore_extra_column, "epoch", values->column ...);
    double ign;
    while(in.read_row(ign, values->value ...))
    {
        /* see below! */ process(values...);
    }
}
```

So far no problem, read_header and read_row are variadic templates, so fine. Calling the member function was a little tricky, however - have a look at the call to the (yet unknown) process function above. Keyword compile time recursion (101010's answer), here we go:

```cpp
void process()
{ }

template <typename ... Bases>
void process(Base* b, Bases* ... values)
{
    b->process();
    process(values ...);
}
```

Define these two functions before the template function, and it works...

Edit: Stealing sizeof...(Bases) + 1 from J.Doe...

Answer (score 0):

With variadic templates you must materialize some short of compile time recursion:

```
template<unsigned int COL>
void func(const std::string &fn, Base &v) {
  ...
}

template<unsigned int COL, typename... Args>
void func(const std::string &fn, Base &v, Args&&... args) {
    ...
    func<COL>(fn, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

compilable example (you will need to fill in the code for reading from the csv file and writing to each target):

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>


template<class Function, class...Ts>
void for_all(Function f, Ts&&...ts)
{
  using expand = int[];
  void(expand{0,
              (f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)), 0)...
             });

}

// some mocked io library
namespace io
{

  template<std::size_t MaxRows>
  struct CSVReader
  {
    CSVReader(const std::string& s)
    {
    }


    template<class...Targets>
      void read_headers(std::tuple<Targets...>& target)
    {
      read_headers_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Targets)>(), target);
    }

    template<class...Targets>
      void read_row(std::tuple<Targets...>& targets)
    {
      read_values_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Targets)>(), targets);
    }

    // support for std::tie
    template<class...Targets>
      void read_row(const std::tuple<Targets...>& targets)
    {
      read_values_impl(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Targets)>(), targets);
    }

  private:
    template<std::size_t...Is, class Tuple>
      void read_headers_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple& target)
    {
      for_all([](auto&& target) {
        // read the header and assign it to target here
      }, std::get<Is>(target)...);
    }

    template<std::size_t...Is, class Tuple>
      void read_values_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple& target)
    {
      for_all([](auto&& target) {
        // read the values and assign it to target here
      }, std::get<Is>(target)...);
    }

  };

}

struct Base
{
  std::string& value();
  void process();
};

template<std::size_t N, class T, class Current = std::tuple<>> struct n_tuple;
template<std::size_t N, class T> using n_tuple_t = typename n_tuple<N, T>::type;

template<std::size_t N, class T, class Current>
struct n_tuple
{
  using type = std::conditional_t<
  N == std::tuple_size<Current>::value, 
  Current, 
  decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<Current>(), std::declval<n_tuple_t<N-1, T>>()))
  >;
};

template<class...Bases>
void col_n(const std::string &fn, Bases&...bases)
{
  constexpr std::size_t column_count = sizeof...(Bases) + 1;
  io::CSVReader<column_count> in(fn);
  using headers_type = n_tuple_t<column_count, std::string>;
  auto headers = headers_type();

  in.read_headers(headers);
  double ign;
  auto value_refs = std::tie(ign, bases.value()...);

  while (in.read_row(value_refs)) {
    // now we only want to process each base
    for_all([](auto&& base) {
      base.process();
    }, bases...);
  }
}
```